# How to create a Mac/PC server app that interacts with iPhone/iPad App?

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi

Can someone please point me in the right direction to create a Mac/PC server app that runs in the background and connects to an iPad app over the local WiFi network?

No matter how I phrase a search on Google it just brings up various apps like Remote Mouse and whatnot and no tutorials or even a hint of where to start.

I just need to send simple commands from iPad to computer over local wifi. A point in the right direction and I can likely fill in the blanks.

Thank you.

Thomas

EDIT: I am using web languages for the iPad version that I will build as a native app using open source tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, then. It actually depends on what you really need. I made the assumption you need real-time and perhaps binary data transfer.

Your best bet is to write your server application using standard C or C++ so it compiles on both as simply as possible.
If you want to avoid all the burden of writing a protocol for service discovery or asking users to enter the ip address of your server you will use a mDNS implementation for your server and your iPhone app.

If I were you I would try bonjour: http://www.apple.com/support/bonjour/
on iPhone You could start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/PublishingServices.html

Once you have your sockets you will have to implement a networking protocol between your server application and your iPhone app.
You will have to be careful about byte ordering and little subtle problems with latency, disconnections and other problems inherent to networking and WiFi.

In windows you will want to register your application as a service and in Mac OS X/UNIX you'll probably want to deamonize it.

Good luck!

Comment: If you want to avoid the burden of using multiple implementations of sockets and such you can try also using the SDL http://www.libsdl.org/

Comment: Using C or C++ for your server app is not mandatory... you can use something else... But using C and C++ modules will allow you to share some code between your server app and your iPhone/Android NDK apps. Depending on your situation it might allow you to save a lot of time and effort if you need to replicate some of the state and logics between the server and the iPhone.

Comment: I just noticed your profile was web oriented. Are you OK with C++?

Comment: Wow. This site is better than I thought. I always come here through Google. Just signed up today, didn't think I'd get so much info so quick. Thank you very much. I will definitely follow the links you provided. 

Yes, I am web oriented. But, I'm also a very good learner. I've look into C/C++ but haven't written anything. I'm sure I can figure it out in time. If not, I always have you. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you need the server to be able to push data to your app? Or will your app be always on and pull data regularly from the server? If you can pull (text, xml, json) data constantly you could write your server side using PHP, ruby or any web server language and serve the scripts with apache or any web server. If what you need is more "real time" then you will want to deal with sockets in C, C++ erlang or any other language that allows you to run your server as an application.

Comment: It would have to be real time. For example, push a button on the iPad and it corresponds to an action in the server app instantaneously. Do you know any good tutorials for sockets in C/C++? Would bonjour be capable of doing this?

Comment: OK, but does the server need to run something even when your client app is not connected? For example in a video game, the game world keeps running and evolving even when no users are connected. Or do you just need the server to return answers to your client apps (respond to queries) in which case a simple LAMP server could do and you could write your client using HTML/js. Bonjour lets you publish and find services on a network. For socket programming you can start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets

Comment: I only need it to work when the iPad is connected... The relationship will basically be push button on ipad > ipad sends button press to server on pc/mac > server does something with button press info... What would you recommend for that?

I'm checking out node.js and sockets.io right now. Do you think that is a good direction for what I need? Can a node.js server be compiled into a .exe and .app to distribute to users?